# Google+ API v1 plus.activities.list returns empty activities for post made with an account whose target audience is 18+ or older

Tags: api, google-plus, google-oauth

I'm calling the Google+ API to grab the [list of activities](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) for a particular user . I'm using the [PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and followed the example for the [service account](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php). I've made the necessary setup in my Google account (enable Google+ API service, setup the keys, etc). I queried the list of activities for a particular user who had setup its target audience as 18+ or older. And everything works. I got a successful response back with the list of activities.  This was back in November 2014. All of a sudden, I'm now getting an empty list of activities in the response. Anybody experienced a similar behaviour?

To eliminate the possibility of issues with my code I started testing with the [api explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list) and Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0. I logged in with an account that is older than 18 years old.
I tried playing around with the settings for the target audience for my Google+ test account and this is what I noticed. If I set the target audience to anyone and make a post. That post is returned from the api explorer. If I switch the target audience to 18+ or older and make a post. That post does not show up in the api explorer. Why is this the case now? I would think that the api would grab my profile from the authenticated call and determine that I'm older than 18 and that I'm allowed to view the post. Anybody knows whether there was a recent change in the API? I swear this was working back in November 2014.

Answer (score 0):

You should [file a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).

Comment: Bug ticket created: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1068&thanks=1068&ts=1421087594